# bash script stuck at the end of a for loop

Tags: bash, docker-machine

I'm trying to deploy $DM_COUNT docker-machines through a script, and write new network configuration to the nodes. The script works fine until the end of the loop and then gets stuck

The script is called from this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
PS4='$LINENO: '

net="10.17.65."
```

The loop starts properly

```
for i in $(seq 1 $DM_COUNT); do
(
name="$PREFIX$DEPLOYMENTNAME$i"
echo "$name"

if [ -z "$DM_NAMES" ]
then
    export DM_NAMES=$name
else
    export DM_NAMES=$DM_NAMES:$name
fi

ip="$net$((4 + i))"
mkdir -p ~/.ssh && touch $_/config &&
tee -a $_ << EOF
Host $name
  Hostname $ip
  User docker
  IdentityFile ~/.docker/machine/machines/$name/id_rsa
EOF

 docker-machine create $name\
                  --driver vmwarevsphere \
                  --vmwarevsphere-cpu-count 4 \
                  --vmwarevsphere-datastore datastore1 \
                  --vmwarevsphere-disk-size 60000 \
                  --vmwarevsphere-memory-size 2048 \
                  --vmwarevsphere-network 'VM\ Network' \
                  --vmwarevsphere-vcenter 10.17.6.218 \
                  --vmwarevsphere-password a \
                  --vmwarevsphere-username root

docker-machine restart "$name"
docker-machine regenerate-certs -f "$name"
echo 'Done provisioning ' "$name"

docker-machine scp -r /certs/ "$name":/root/certs/
docker-machine ssh "$name" sudo mkdir /var/lib/boot2docker/certs

docker-machine ssh "$name" sudo cp /root/certs/*.crt /var/lib/boot2docker/certs/

echo 'Done copying self-signed certificates'

echo "
    # configure eht1 (czlocal1)
    sudo ip addr flush dev eth1
    sudo ip route del default
    sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.254

    # configure eth2 (czlocal2)
    sudo ip addr flush dev eth0
    sudo ip route add default via 192.168.2.254

    # configure eth3 (czlocaldhcp)
    sudo ip addr flush dev eth0

    # configure eth0 (mgmt)
    sudo ip addr flush dev eth0
    ip addr add 10.17.65.10$i/24 dev eth0
    ip route add 10.17.36.0/24 via 10.17.65.1 dev eth0
    ip route add 10.17.33.0/24 via 10.17.65.1 dev eth0

    # configure eth2 (czlocal2)
    sudo ip addr flush dev eth2
    ip addr add 192.168.2.$i/24

    # configure eth3 (czlocaldhcp)
    sudo ip addr flush dev eth3
" | docker-machine ssh "$name" "sudo tee /var/lib/boot2docker/bootsync.sh"

echo "
    sudo ip route del default
    sudo ip route add default via 192.168.$1.254
" | docker-machine ssh "$name" "sudo tee ~/switch_default_gateway.sh"

echo "
    alias local1='ip route del default && ip route add default via 192.168.1.254'
    alias local2='ip route del default && ip route add default via 192.168.2.254'
    alias dhcp='ip route del default && ip route add default via 172.0.0.254'
" | docker-machine ssh "$name" "sudo tee -a ~/.bashrc > /dev/null"

echo 'Done writing scripts'

docker-machine ssh "$name" "sudo chmod +x /var/lib/boot2docker/bootsync.sh"
docker-machine ssh "$name" "sudo chmod +x ~/switch_default_gateway.sh"
docker-machine ssh "$name" "source ~/.bashrc"

jq '.Driver.IPAddress = $newVal' --arg newVal '10.17.65.10'$i ~/.docker/machine/machines/"$name"/config.json > tmp.$$.json && mv tmp.$$.json ~/.docker/machine/machines/"$name"/config.json

echo 'Done deploying docker machines'

) &
done
```

Everything until this point executes fine, then the script is stuck. If I provide any input on the shell it exits.

```
tee -a ~/.ssh/config << EOF
Host *
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
EOF
```

The last part never gets executed

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you don't have a 'non breakable space' (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) between your **<<** and **EOF**?

Anyway, your initial script, and the indicated lines at the end of your question is not the same (the one involving **tee** command), can you update your question to fit the final version of your script?

Comment: Thank's for your response. These are two parts of the same script. First the machines are registered in the conf file and at the end, I disable StrictHostKeyChecking for all hosts.

Comment: I'm moderately certain concerning the whitespace. Even if I remove the tee at the bottom, the script is stuck at the done.

Comment: And why is there a final **&** just before the done keyword? Are you trying to work on each iteration in parallel or something like that?

Comment: Yes they run parallel

Comment: Yo, so this is the issue, because all of your parallel execution are working on the same file ~/.ssh/config; I guess the script can't manage several > <<EOF in the same file, simultaneously.

Comment: Sadly it's not that either. Even after removing those code parts completely the script is still stuck at the done.

Comment: If I run the script without the & at the end, it finishes, so the issue seems connected to that.

Comment: Do you really earn working in parallel?
If yes, you should update this script part to have a different configuration file for each iteration, but then you should have some final instructions to merge everything in your real SSH configuration file.

Comment: @ChristophZangerle:  IMHO `mkdir -p ~/.ssh && touch $_/config && tee -a $_` is too cute by half. Just because you can use syntax like that doesn't mean you should. Get it to work first! Keep it Simple ;-) . AND are you running it in debug mode to see the "state"? (`set -x` or `set -vx`? with `set +x`, `set +vx` to turn off). Good luck.

Comment: Hey, thank's for the comment, I do agree I'm not too used to bash so I might be a bit too playfull ^^ The issue is the script works until I add the & to run it in parallel, I think it might be that one of the iterations is stuck while waiting for a response from a docker-machine whicht puts the whole thing on hold and the continuation is not working. But well it's a guess. I run it with set -x but so far nothing helpfull.

Comment: Sorry you're not making much progress. If you really need it to run in parallel, you might look at `xargs` or gnu-parallel. There are many Q/A here for both. ALSO, all of your code confuses the issue. You'll get more help if you can demonstrate your problem in less that 10 lines of code. Does commenting out large blocks of your script make any difference? If yes, then post new Q with the smallest set of code that illustrates the problem. Read [mcve] and try to work with that. Good luck.

Comment: @ChristophZangerle even if you use another way to parallelism your iterations' execution (I agree with gnu-parallel interest), you will still have hazardous behaviour if all execution work on the same ~/.ssh/config file.
We can keep on working on your script, but yes, it would be interesting to have a very shorter version of it.